# How can I execute command inside a Docker container from a Composer image?

Tags: docker

I am using `docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/app composer/composer:1.1-alpine install`. But, I need to execute some Bash codes before that, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enter a running container by running the command:

```
docker exec -it <container-name> sh
```